# ASP.net MVC Form - field for each model properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a ASP.NET MVC Website with a Configuration View.

I have a "Configuration" class with string and bool properties

In the view, I would like to display a label + field for each property of my Configuration class. A "Textbox" for the string, a checkbox for  the bool.

But then, in my "Submit" button, I need to use the entered values in a JavaScript method...

What is the best way to do that ?

I have :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
    {
       <label>@(property.DisplayName??property.PropertyName)</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => property.PropertyName)
     }
}
```

But how do I display a checkbox for the bool properties ?

And Then How to get all the values in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can Use **Ajax.BeginForm** in your Form and Collect your Data
at your [Post] Method via ( **FormCollection** )
all your element with its values will be get

- Update

Example:-

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(FormCollection fc)
{
      //TO DO Something
}
```

and in Your View will be Something like that

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions))

{
```

This will help to hold your data in server side very much
and about How to get the values Using Javascrip 
you can Define var to Hold your Selector

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example ? First I use my "Configuration" class as model. Then I use "@using (Ajax.BeginForm())". What do I have to put in the ajaxOptions parameter ? Then, I need to loop into all my "configuration" properties and dispay the correct field (textbox or checkbox). Then, how do I get the values in my JavaScript method ?

Comment: I've Update to look at may it will help @ your Issue

Comment: Thanks! It helps. I'm a beginner and it's the first ASP.NET mvc form that I create... So then, what do I have to do in the "TO DO Something" to use the form values and return a Json object ? And maybe, do you have an idea how to loop into my model properties and display the correct field type (texbbox for string, checkbox for bool,..) ?